# Сложность с D3D хуком

Tags: c++, dll, directx, hook

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать меню для игрушки, но не могу разобраться в функции, которая крашит программу после инъекции. Опишу все подробно с комментариями, если я не прав, пожалуйста поправьте:
Создаю поток в процессе (инжект работает нормально) с таким содержимым:

```
    DWORD*vtbl = 0;
    //Здесь я записываю начальный адрес модуля 
    DWORD hD3D9 = (DWORD)LoadLibraryA("d3d9.dll");
    //ищу функцию Direct3DCreate или что то другое?
    DWORD table = MemHack->FindPattern(hD3D9, 0x128000, (PBYTE)"\xC7\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x86", "xx????xx????xx");//
    // со смещением в 2 байта копируем указатель
    memcpy(&vtbl, (void*)(table + 2), 4);
```

Здесь table = 6ace76d3. Вот кусок памяти:

```
d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+54AC - E8 71000000           - call        d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+5522
d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+54B1 - 33 C0                 - xor eax,eax
d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+54B3 - C7 06 9C86CD6A        - mov [esi],d3d9.dll+869C { [6ACD9D30] }
d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+54B9 - 89 86 08310000        - mov [esi+00003108],eax
d3d9.Direct3DCreate9Ex+54BF - 89 86 00310000        - mov [esi+00003100],eax
```

Далее идет вызов функции, который крашит программу:

```
// vtbl[42] указывает на функцию endScene размером 5 байт?
pEndScene = (oEndScene)Mem->Create_Hook((PBYTE)vtbl[42], (PBYTE)myEndScene, 5);
```

Приведу код функции, который в общем представлении я не понял:

```
void * cMemory::Create_Hook(BYTE *src, const BYTE *dst, const int len)
{
    BYTE *jmp;
    DWORD dwback;
    DWORD jumpto, newjump;

    VirtualProtect(src,len,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&dwback);
    // вот отсюда я не понял зачем эта проверка вообще нужна
    if(src[0] == 0xE9)
    {
        jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(10);
        jumpto = (*(DWORD*)(src+1))+((DWORD)src)+5;
        newjump = (jumpto-(DWORD)(jmp+5));
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp+1) = newjump;
        jmp += 5;
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp+1) = (DWORD)(src-jmp);
    }
    else
    {
        jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(5+len);
        memcpy(jmp,src,len);
        jmp += len;
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp+1) = (DWORD)(src+len-jmp)-5;
    }
    src[0] = 0xE9;
    *(DWORD*)(src+1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5;

    for(int i = 5; i < len; i++)
        src[i] = 0x90;

    VirtualProtect(src,len,dwback,&dwback);
    // здесь указатель на функцию?
    return (jmp-len);
}
```

Comment: @Arhad SO не имеет никакого отношения к РФ. вопросы про реверс-инжиниринг тут вполне разрешены - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070/

Comment: cc @Duracell - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070/

Comment: @PashaPash, я Вам рекомендую ознакомится с УК РФ (ст. 1201) и подобными законами Вашей страны, если Вы не проживаете на территории РФ!  Устанавливая "игру", автор принимал лицензионное соглашение -  закон - превыше правил форума! (не говоря уже моральных принципах и нормах (если это онлайн игра, то мне вообще не о чем говорить)).

Comment: @PashaPash, если игра с открытым исходным кодом и "лицензиатом" разрешено вносить любые изменения в исходный код - то это другое дело! Тут я не спорю.

Comment: Я хочу в C&C:Generals меню вставить, её точно не поддерживают, а вот насчет исходного кода это да, его нет. Я руководствуюсь тем, что для C&C: Tiberium Wars выложили алгоритмы по которым она шифровалась и теперь ее можно реинженерить для создания всяких модов, а она гораздо позже генералов вышла

Comment: @helldrg, ладно помогу, это моя любимая игра детства, но только потому что это оффлайн игра и очень старая! Позже выложу полный код.

Comment: @Duracell на SO не действую законы РФ и законы моей страны (которые, кстати, тоже не запрещают реверс-инжиниринг). Если вы хотите закрепить запрет реверс-инжиниринга в правилах - создайте пост на мете. Но могу сразу сказать, что дотнетчики будут этим сильно недовольны :)

Comment: @PashaPash, как же принятие лицензионного соглашения? Это ведь все равно, что подписать договор например...Понятное дело что за взлом старой игры  никто не будет подавать в суд, но все же это факт...Так же мне не понятен момент, когда я лично видел темы о взломах и о помощи в этом - их тут же минусовали и говорили, что яко бы запрещено, я следовал этим принципам "наглядности", ну ладно раз разрешено - то мне не имеет смысла спорить с Вами, тем более Вы модератор и Вас не просто так выбрали.

Comment: @Duracell откуда вы знаете, принимал ли его топикастер? вдруг он игру в zip нашел, и лицензионное соглашение в процессе установки не видел. Минусовать - можно. Удалять и закрывать на основании подозрений о несоответствии законам РФ - нельзя.

Comment: @Duracell Моя тоже любимая игра =)

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо вам за поддержку!

Comment: А тут лайки можно вам поставить?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши ошибки:

- Игра написана на directX8, а не 9 версии, Вы пытаетесь хукнуть 9 версию, собственно `LoadLibraryA("d3d9.dll")`, нужно `LoadLibraryA("d3d8.dll")` и в таблице виртуальные методы там, на сколько я помню, имеют немного другую последовательность (для проверки того, какую версию dx использует приложения нужно всего лишь открыть отладчик и просмотреть список загруженных модулей или посмотреть инфо в википедии).
- Вы пытаетесь(скорее всего, это мои догадки) сделать иньекцию кода в процесс generals.exe, но это просто дочернее окно и оно не выполняет функции отрисовки игрового мира\меню и т.д., Вам нужен процесс game.dat.

Вечером, когда приду домой, постараюсь переделать Ваш код в рабочее состояние и дополню ответ. Если Вам интересно, можете почитать [интересную статью по Вашей теме](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/34411-run-time-directx-hooking-using-code-injection-and-vtable/).

> UPD:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <d3d8.h>
#include <d3dx8.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx8.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "LIBCI.lib" )

#include "MessageControll.h"
#include "ConsoleControll.h"
//"Game.dat"+0056C9A4

// Hook Function
HRESULT WINAPI HookedPresent(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, CONST RECT* pSourceRect, CONST RECT* pDestRect, HWND hDestWindowOverride, CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion);
HRESULT WINAPI HookedReset(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *params);

// Orig Function
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* tPresent)(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, CONST RECT* pSourceRect, CONST RECT* pDestRect, HWND hDestWindowOverride, CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion);
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI *tReset)(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *pp);

DWORD origReset = 0, origPresent = 0;

tPresent _tPresent = nullptr;
tReset _tReset = nullptr;

ID3DXFont* pFont = nullptr;

void createFont(IDirect3DDevice8* pDevice)
{
        LOGFONT log_font = {
            50, //height
            0,  //width; 
            0,  // lfEscapement; 
            0,  //lfOrientation; 
            FW_BOLD, // lfWeight; 
            FALSE, // lfItalic; 
            FALSE, // lfUnderline; 
            FALSE, // lfStrikeOut; 
            DEFAULT_CHARSET, // lfCharSet; 
            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, //lfOutPrecision; 
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, // lfClipPrecision; 
            ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,// lfQuality; 
            DEFAULT_PITCH,// lfPitchAndFamily; 
            "Tahoma"// lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE]; 
        };

        HFONT font = CreateFont(10, 10, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, false, false, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, 0, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Arial");

        if (D3DXCreateFontIndirect(pDevice, &log_font, &pFont) != D3D_OK)
        {
            console("D3DXCreateFontIndirect error!");
        }
}

VOID D3DX_Font(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 Device_Interface)
{
    RECT Rect = { 0,0,1000,1000 };

    //if (Device_Interface != NULL)
    //{
    //  HFONT Logical_Font_Characteristics = CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, "Arial");

    //  if (Logical_Font_Characteristics != NULL)
    //  {
    //      D3DXCreateFont(Device_Interface, Logical_Font_Characteristics, &pFont);
    //      DeleteObject(Logical_Font_Characteristics);
    //  }
    //}

    if (pFont != NULL)
    {
        pFont->Begin();
        pFont->DrawText("StackOverflow.ru!", -1, &Rect, 0, 0xFFFF0000);
        pFont->End();
    }
}
//=========================================================



//if (bDrawText && m_pFont)
//{
//  PrintTextB(m_pFont,
//      250, 20, //x, y
//      255, 255, 255, 255, //color values (and then alpha)
//      "Testing 1234567890!!!");
//}

//My custom PrintText Function:
//void drawText(const D3DXVECTOR4& area, const DWORD& color, TCHAR *text, ...)
//{
//  TCHAR buf[1024]{};
//
//  RECT FontRect = {
//
//      (long)area.x,
//      (long)area.y,
//      (long)area.x + (long)area.z,
//      (long)area.y + (long)area.w
//  };
//
//  va_list vaList;
//  va_start(vaList, text);
//
//#ifdef UNICODE
//  vswprintf_s(buf, text, vaList);
//#else
//  vsprintf_s(buf, text, vaList);
//#endif
//
//  va_end(vaList);
//
//  pFont->Begin();
//  pFont->DrawText(buf, -1, &FontRect, 0, color);
//  pFont->End();
//}

void* DetourCreate(BYTE *src, const BYTE *dst, const int len)
{
    BYTE *jmp;
    DWORD dwback, dwold;
    DWORD jumpto, newjump;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwback);

    if (src[0] == 0xE9)
    {
        jmp = (PBYTE)malloc(10);
        VirtualProtect(jmp, 10, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwold);
        jumpto = (*(DWORD*)(src + 1)) + ((DWORD)src) + 5;
        newjump = (jumpto - (DWORD)(jmp + 5));
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = newjump;
        jmp += 5;
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(src - jmp);
    }
    else
    {
        jmp = (PBYTE)malloc(5 + len);
        VirtualProtect(jmp, 5 + len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwold);
        memcpy(jmp, src, len);
        jmp += len;
        jmp[0] = 0xE9;
        *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(src + len - jmp) - 5;
    }

    src[0] = 0xE9;

    *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5;

    for (int i = 5; i < len; i++)
    {
        src[i] = 0x90;
    }

    VirtualProtect(src, len, dwback, &dwback);

    return (jmp - len);
}

void GetDevice9Methods()
{
    D3DDISPLAYMODE ds{};
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS pp{};
    IDirect3DDevice8* dev{};

    HMODULE hD3D8Dll = GetModuleHandle("d3d8.dll");

    //console("address \"d3d8.dll\" [%#x]", hD3D8Dll);

    //Инициализируем свой девайс, чтобы узнать адреса функций ресета и презента в виртуальной таблице методов
    if (hD3D8Dll)
    {
        IDirect3D8* d3d8 = Direct3DCreate8(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

        //console("address \"IDirect3D8\" [%#x]", d3d8);

        if (d3d8->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &ds) != D3D_OK)
        {
            d3d8->Release();
            return;
        }

        pp.Windowed = 1;
        pp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY_VSYNC;
        pp.BackBufferFormat = ds.Format;

        if (d3d8->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, GetForegroundWindow(), D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &pp, &dev) == D3D_OK)
        {
            if (dev)
            {
                //Копируем адреса виртуальных методов
                origReset = *((DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)dev) + 14);
                origPresent = *((DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)dev) + 15);

                //console("address \"Reset method\" [%#x]", origReset);
                //console("address \"Present method\" [%#x]", origPresent);

                dev->Release();
                d3d8->Release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d3d8->Release();
            return;
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI InitThread(HINSTANCE hinstDLL)
{
    //t_con.create();

    GetDevice9Methods();

    if (origReset && origPresent)
    {
        _tPresent = (tPresent)DetourCreate((PBYTE)origPresent, (PBYTE)HookedPresent, 5);
        _tReset = (tReset)DetourCreate((PBYTE)origReset, (PBYTE)HookedReset, 5);
    }

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END))
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    //t_con.del();

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hinstDLL, 0);

    return 1;
}

HRESULT WINAPI HookedPresent(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, CONST RECT* pSourceRect, CONST RECT* pDestRect, HWND hDestWindowOverride, CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion)
{
    if (!pFont)
    {
        createFont(pDevice);
    }
    else
    {
        D3DX_Font(pDevice);
    }

    D3DRECT rec = { 10, 10, 30, 30 };

    //pDevice->Clear(1, &rec, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0xFFFF0000, 1.0f, 0);

    return  _tPresent(pDevice, pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion);
}

HRESULT WINAPI HookedReset(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice, D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *params)
{
    return _tReset(pDevice, params);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH://Вызывается первым 
        CreateThread(0, 0, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(InitThread), hinstDLL, 0, 0);
        return 1;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH://вызывается после освобождения библиотеки
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH://вызывается при создании потока
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH://вызывается после разрушения потока
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Как пофиксить проблемы с нехваткой libci:

1. Скачать саму либу и заинклудить в проект;
2. [Заинклудить дополнительные зависимости, как сказано тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418766/c-unresolved-external-symbol-sprintf-and-sscanf-in-visual-studio-2015)

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46260/discussion-on-answer-by-duracell---d3d-).